# Error when adding multiple entities into TypeOrmModule

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm having issues adding a second entity into my Nest project. It works fine with just one entity `Video`, but now when I have added another `User`, I get the error `No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?` on compilation.

What am I doing wrong here?

`database.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { ConfigModule } from "../config/config.module";
import { ConfigService } from "../config/config.service";
import { Video } from "../videos/video.entity";
import { User } from "../auth/user.entity";

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'postgres' as 'postgres',
                host: configService.dbHost,
                port: configService.dbPort,
                username: configService.dbUsername,
                password: configService.dbPassword,
                database: configService.dbName,
                entities: [Video, User],
                synchronize: true
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService]
        })
    ]
})

export class DatabaseModule {}
```

`user.entity.ts`

```
import { BaseEntity, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm";

Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry.. typo by me. Forgot to decorate the entity properly. Should be `@Entity()`